# SSRS local install browse to portal gives "Could not load folder contents" error

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Newly installed SQL Server Reporting Services on my local machine.  Configuration Tools runs fine, database is created, virtual directories and portal site all created successfully.

But, when I browse to the portal, I get this, even though I am an admin on my local machine.

How can I get the necessary permissions to browse the portal locally?  I've browsed to \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS and have unrestricted permissions.

Update:  Snapshot of Users table from ReportServer db:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Your domain/local account permissions don't really mean anything inside SSRS, only your account SID is used to authenticate you. The SSRS tables are officially "undocumented" by Microsoft, but reports are stored in the Catalog table, roles in Roles, users in Users, and access to reports is controlled through entries in the Policies and PolicyUserRole tables. The only account that would have access to everything out of the box would be the local Administrator account with the *-501 SID, so if you could login with that account you can start granting access to others via the GUI.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks so much for the response.  I'm a little unclear on what you mean by the *-501 SID.  I've added a pic of the Users table above, and it looks exactly like the Users table on an Azure VM that is working as expected.  If you have any more insight please let me know.  Thanks again.

Comment: See this page, I think it might address your specific issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/configure-a-native-mode-report-server-for-local-administration-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield! But that article applies to older os, this is Windows 10.  Much of the configuration they describe is within the web portal, which I cannot browse to.

Comment: Try logging in to the SSRS portal using the machine's Administrator account - the actual Administrator account, as opposed to a different account that happens to be in the Administrators group. You should be able to browse all content using the Administrator account and apply roles and permissions from there.

Answer (score 0):

From within the SSRS website, you may have to assign the AppPool account at least `Browser` permissions to that folder. Click `Manage Folder` at the top right and assign the AppPool account at least `Browser` permission.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  However, the issue is I cannot even get to the SSRS website, see the image above.

Comment: @Mike. What does your SSRS error log say? In SQL Server Reporting Services 2016 or earlier: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS13.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`